# APNs, FCM or GCM token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, token

How apple or google specify a token to a user or app or maybe device?

for example
for user X, with Device Iphone7, and Facebook,  the apple generate one token
or 
for user X, with Device Iphone7 the apple generate one 
or any others...
also How google?

another question is in Web Application, How they specify tokens?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding your english, please try fixing it even if it means using only very simple sentences.

Comment: i think it is better

Comment: every phone receives a token once they install the app `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

Comment: You meanT a token is unique for every phone and app?
and how web application?

Answer (score 2):

An FCM token is also known as a *device instance ID*; it identifies that specific app on that specific device.

If the same app is installed on another device, it will get a different device instance ID. This is even the case when it's the same user installing the same app, the instance ID on each phone will be unique.

When a different app is installed on the same device, it also gets its own device instance ID. So different apps will never share the token, no matter if they are on the same phone.

In this respect if you have multiple profiles on the same (Android) phone, they count as separate phones: if you install the same app on the same phone under two profiles, each instance of the app will get its own instance ID.

All of this means that you can target a specific app, on a specific profile of a specific phone with its token.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, Well, How about APNS and also How Web application?

Comment: iOS works the same. Web works similarly, but it more limited. For example: you can't subscribe to topics on FCM.js, nor can you send messages to web clients through the Firebase console.

Comment: You mean APNS  specify a token for Device->user(maybe multi profile)->app
and in the web application, if i open my gmail, in a multi windows in chrome, microsoft edge,firefox  Simultaneous, how they send me a message